# Windows 8 update error code 80072EFE? What's  the solution?

Tags: windows, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I keep getting the error `code 80072EFE` and windows is not installing 11 important updates.

Also .NET framework 3.5 is not getting installed it keeps saying that its not able to download. My internet connection is working fine and I am able to browse over the entire internet. I have not changed any of the settings and I am running on Windows 8. The error code I get for .NET is `0x800F0906`.

Windows live essential are also not getting downloaded. Is there some issue with the Microsoft servers these days?

Comment: Have you tried to install it form control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## .NET Framework Issue

However you can install the `.NET Framework 3.5` without downloading. Just go to control panel and select the `Turn Windows feature on or off` and scroll down to see the `.Net Framework 3.5` and select the check box and press **OK**. Windows will install it automatically.

If it does not do the trick then insert the Windows 8 installation disk and open the **Source Folder** and find the **SSX** and copy this folder to `C:\Temp`. Now run the command prompt as admin and type the following command...

> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:c:\temp\sxs /LimitAccess

Hope it will help for that. The guide is from [here](http://www.forumswindows8.com/general-discussion/error-0x800f0906-when-installing-net-3-5-windows-8-release-preview-6637.htm).

### Update Issue

From [Microsoft support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/unable-to-get-windows-update-network-diagnostic/87f54f1a-1175-4c63-8838-7a56b9f3f3b6). However solution is not for Windows 8 but I think its worth to give a try to it.

> Error 80072EFE is related to Update server closing the connection.
>   Mosty likely, the computer may be infected with ROOTKITS.
>   Try to run [TDSSKILLER](http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/tdsskiller.exe) to find any rootkits.

You can also run the malwarebytes to check the infection on your system.